# How to write CSS within JADE/PUG template files

Tags: pug

I'm essentially trying to achieve the following:

```html
<div class="mdl-tooltip" for="tt1">
```

within a .pug file. I know how to include the css, but unsure of where to start looking for information to include the targeted part `for="tt1"`.

Can someone point me in the right direction to find the answer, before I actually ask for the answer..!

So what I have so far is:

```
button.mdl-button.mdl-js-button About
 i#about.material-icons.accent info
 .mdl-tooltip(for="#about") About the Site
```

Alas this doesn't seem to produce the tooltip..! When I look at the output source the html is all in the correct format so far as I can tell.

```html
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--colored nav">About&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons accent" id="about">info</i>
              <div class="mdl-tooltip" for="#about">About Paddle Log</div>
            </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if this is the cause of your problem, but there is definitely no need to include the `#` in the value of the `for` attribute ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp)).

This should be sufficient: `.mdl-tooltip(for="about")`

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer solves your issue, please mark it as accepted.